# Split not displaying in current format

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
var mystring = "save 'myfile.txt' 'this is the content'";
```

I need it to break like this:

```
var command = mystring[0];
var filename = mystring[1];
var content = mystring[2];
```

I am using this:

```
var mystring = message.content.split("'' ,");
```

This is not showing anything

How can I do this?

Comment: please add the values of the result.

Comment: What is the comma for? You don't have a comma in your string. Not sure what you are trying to do, is `split("' '")` not enough?

Comment: Split with a regex, e.g. `mystring.split(/ '|' '/)`

Comment: What result you want exactly? Please display results you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the parts and use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
var string = "save 'myfile.txt' 'this is the content'",
    [, command, filename, content] = string.match(/(.*) '(.*)' '(.*)'/);
    
console.log(command);
console.log(filename);
console.log(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression for your split: `mystring.split(/'?\s*'/)`

```js
var mystring = "save 'myfile.txt' 'this is the content'";
var [command, filename, content] = mystring.split(/'?\s*'/);
console.log({command, filename, content});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const mystring = message.content.split(" ");
const command = mystring[0];
const filename = mystring[1].substr(1,mystring[1].length - 2);
const content = mystring[2].substr(1,mystring[2].length - 2);
```